# phpmyadmin javascript desginer error

Tags: javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin

this is the error i get when i go into the designer window to edit my relations, is there any fix?
https://i.gyazo.com/3b53746ab32691a1002f301d38e09c99.png
Some more info, i use chrome but i get the same error in firefox, IE. so i dont think its the browser that is the problem

```
{
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "message": "Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null",
        "stack": [
            {
                "line": 235,
                "func": "",
                "context": [
                    "                lastException = null;",
                    "                notifyHandlers.apply(null, [stack, null].concat(args));",
                    "            }",
                    "        }, (stack.incomplete ? 2000 : 0));",
                    "",
                    "        throw ex; // re-throw to propagate to the top level (and cause wind//...",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    report.subscribe = subscribe;",
                    "    report.unsubscribe = unsubscribe;",
                    "    return report;"
                ],
                "column": "",
                "filename": "tracekit/tracekit.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Re_load",
                "line": 351,
                "column": "66",
                "context": [
                    "",
                    "                    row_offset_top = 0;",
                    "                    var tab_hide_button = document.getElementById('id_hide_//...",
                    "                    if (tab_hide_button.innerHTML == 'v') {",
                    "                        row_offset_top = document.getElementById(contr[K][k//...",
                    "                            + '.' + contr[K][key][key2][key3][1]).offsetTop;",
                    "                    }",
                    "",
                    "                    var y2 =",
                    "                          document.getElementById(contr[K][key][key2][key3]//...",
                    "                        + row_offset_top"
                ],
                "filename": "pmd/move.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Main",
                "line": 237,
                "column": "5",
                "context": [
                    "    sm_x += document.getElementById('osn_tab').offsetLeft;",
                    "    sm_y += document.getElementById('osn_tab').offsetTop;",
                    "    Osn_tab_pos();",
                    "    Canvas_pos();",
                    "    Small_tab_refresh();",
                    "    Re_load();",
                    "    id_hint = document.getElementById('pmd_hint');",
                    "    if (isIE) {",
                    "        General_scroll();",
                    "    }",
                    "}"
                ],
                "filename": "pmd/move.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.",
                "line": 30,
                "column": "5",
                "context": [
                    "",
                    "    server = $(\"#script_server\").html();",
                    "    db     = $(\"#script_db\").html();",
                    "    token  = $(\"#script_token\").html();",
                    "",
                    "    Main();",
                    "});",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "// CodeMirror version 3.15",
                    "//"
                ],
                "filename": "pmd/init.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.new_func",
                "line": 249,
                "column": "33",
                "context": [
                    "     */",
                    "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                    "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                    "            var new_func = function () {",
                    "                try {",
                    "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                    "                } catch (x) {",
                    "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                    "                }",
                    "            };",
                    "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
                ],
                "filename": "error_report.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.v.event.dispatch",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "38053",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                    "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                    "",
                    "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                    "/**",
                    " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                    " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.$event.dispatch",
                "line": 374,
                "column": "19",
                "context": [
                    "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                    "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                    "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                    "\t\treturn;",
                    "\t}",
                    "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                    "};",
                    "",
                    "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                    "var touchHooks = ",
                    "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.o.handle.u",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "33916",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                    "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                    "",
                    "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                    "/**",
                    " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                    " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Object.v.event.trigger",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "36647",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                    "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                    "",
                    "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                    "/**",
                    " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                    " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "HTMLDocument.",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "44416",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                    "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                    "",
                    "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                    "/**",
                    " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                    " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "Function.v.extend.each",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "14543",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                    "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                    "",
                    "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                    "/**",
                    " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                    " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
            }
        ],
        "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36",
        "incomplete": "false",
        "partial": "true",
        "uri": "db_structure.php?target="
    },
    "script_name": "db_structure.php",
    "pma_version": "4.1.14",
    "browser_name": "CHROME",
    "browser_version": "50.0.2661.102",
    "user_os": "Win",
    "server_software": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36",
    "locale": "en",
    "configuration_storage": "enabled",
    "php_version": "5.5.8",
    "microhistory": {
        "pages": [
            "",
            {
                "hash": "tbl_relation.php?db=web-is-gr12w&table=fly&server=1&target=&token=6ffbdb947f2803edac9ccd1b715e5139",
                "params": {
                    "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                    "safari_browser": "0",
                    "querywindow_height": "400",
                    "querywindow_width": "600",
                    "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                    "lang": "en",
                    "server": "1",
                    "text_dir": "ltr",
                    "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                    "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                    "confirm": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "hash": "sql.php?db=web-is-gr12w&table=fly&server=1&target=&token=6ffbdb947f2803edac9ccd1b715e5139",
                "params": {
                    "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                    "safari_browser": "0",
                    "querywindow_height": "400",
                    "querywindow_width": "600",
                    "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                    "lang": "en",
                    "server": "1",
                    "text_dir": "ltr",
                    "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                    "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                    "confirm": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "hash": "tbl_select.php?db=web-is-gr12w&table=fly&server=1&target=&token=6ffbdb947f2803edac9ccd1b715e5139",
                "params": {
                    "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                    "safari_browser": "0",
                    "querywindow_height": "400",
                    "querywindow_width": "600",
                    "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                    "lang": "en",
                    "server": "1",
                    "text_dir": "ltr",
                    "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                    "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                    "confirm": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "hash": "tbl_change.php?db=web-is-gr12w&table=fly&server=1&target=&token=6ffbdb947f2803edac9ccd1b715e5139",
                "params": {
                    "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                    "safari_browser": "0",
                    "querywindow_height": "400",
                    "querywindow_width": "600",
                    "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                    "lang": "en",
                    "server": "1",
                    "text_dir": "ltr",
                    "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                    "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                    "confirm": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "hash": "db_structure.php?db=web-is-gr12w&table=&server=1&target=&token=6ffbdb947f2803edac9ccd1b715e5139",
                "params": {
                    "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                    "safari_browser": "0",
                    "querywindow_height": "400",
                    "querywindow_width": "600",
                    "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                    "lang": "en",
                    "server": "1",
                    "text_dir": "ltr",
                    "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                    "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                    "confirm": "true"
                }
            },
            {
                "hash": "db_events.php?db=web-is-gr12w&table=&server=1&target=&token=6ffbdb947f2803edac9ccd1b715e5139",
                "params": {
                    "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                    "safari_browser": "0",
                    "querywindow_height": "400",
                    "querywindow_width": "600",
                    "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                    "lang": "en",
                    "server": "1",
                    "text_dir": "ltr",
                    "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                    "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                    "confirm": "true"
                }
            }
        ],
        "current_index": "6"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does console shows anything? Wich version of phpmyadmin is it? everything else is fine?

Comment: everything els is working ok, 4.1.14 is the version we use